# C free memory from struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, free

The assignment is to create a struct array with 10 elements as "students" and each have a score and an ID.  There are some things I am not allowed to change in the code (like anything in main).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student* allocate(){
    struct student* array = malloc(10 * sizeof(struct student));
    return array;
}

void deallocate(struct student* stud){
    int i = 0;
    for(;i<10;i++)
        free(&stud[i]);
}
```

So this compiles fine and the rest of the code runs fine but then the core dumps when it gets to the free().  Also, this is the main that my professor gave me and told me not to change.  There was no call to the deallocate function so now I am wondering if it automatically gets called when main is done or if he left it out by mistake.  I added it in because I think that seems reasonable.

```
int main(){
  struct student* stud = allocate();
  generate(stud);
  output(stud);
  sort(stud);
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("%d %d\n", stud[i].id,stud[i].score);
  }
  printf("Avg: %f \n", avg(stud));
  printf("Min: %d \n", min(stud));
  deallocate(stud);    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am compiling use gcc by the way.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How many calls to `malloc()` are there?  How many calls to `free()`?  Why is the number different?  How can you stop it being different?  For each call to `malloc()`, there should be one `free()`.  (If you use `realloc()`, it can throw a spanner in the counting works — it can allocate, reallocate _or_ free memory — but the concept applies.)

Comment: Why you do `free` for each of 10 `struct student` element but the `malloc` is only for the base pointer? Your `deallocate` has to contain only one `free( stud )`.

Comment: Your `main()` that is, presumably, unmodified per instructions, shows a call to `deallocate()`; what is the problem?  That you had to modify the code to make the call?  The `deallocate()` function will not be called automatically.  Something in the code must make that call.

Comment: So your professor gave you code and told you not to change it. You changed it because you "think that seems reasonable". OK.

Comment: Your `for` loop is written: `int i = 0;
    for(;i<10;i++)
        free(&stud[i]);` — it would be better written as `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        free(&stud[i]);` or, if you're stuck with a C89 compiler, as `int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        free(&stud[i]);`.  These keep the controls more clearly together.

Comment: @Hypino My question is how do I correctly free the memory I have allocated without the core being dumped as I said.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There's only one call to the allocate function and I know there only needs to be one call to free.  I'm not sure what you mean by the number being different.  I am not using realloc.

Comment: @i486 I don't know? I guess that's what I am doing wrong, thanks!

Comment: Well, my point about the counts being different is that you have a loop that calls `free()` 10 times — compared to the one `malloc()` — which means you have a problem, do you not?

Comment: @melpomene Well his main didn't even compile the way it was so I assumed it was a mistake that a function he wanted implemented was never called.  So yes it was reasonable, backed up by my professor, too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Yes I do have a problem and that is why I am here.... I guess that's my problem?

Comment: That's your problem (or, at least, one major problem), though if the `deallocate()` code isn't called, your faulty implementation would not reveal itself. [RotatingPieces](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2736432/rotatingpieces)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39797728/) is spot on — worthy of acceptance. The [fix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39799226/) from [izzzi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6902276/izzzi) spells out exactly what you need as the result — assuming `deallocate()` is called somewhere along the line. I tried to explain how to think about this — one `malloc`, one `free`.

Comment: Note that the comments about 'not changing the code in `main`' arise from your mentioning that it was not to be changed.  Since you got an amended version of the immutable code from your professor, you should consider whether (you need) to update the question to remove the observations about changing the immutable.  We can then flag the comments about the changes as obsolete and they'll be removed.

Answer (score 4):

You `(m)allocated` the 10-students array as 1 contiguous block of memory with 1 `malloc` call (this is correct).

To free this you only use `free` once on the first array element. This frees the whole contiguous block of memory  which is the whole 10-students array.

Answer (score 1):

Hey haha I think were in the same class. I am doing this same program. This is how I did my deallocate function and there are no memory leaks or dumps:

```
void deallocate(struct student* stud){
    free(stud);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! Did you have to add the call to the function in main?